# How to keep M2_REPO variable dynamic in Aspect Path of an Eclipse Java/AspectJ run configuration?

Tags: eclipse, maven, configuration, aspectj, launch

I'm trying to create a "Java/AspectJ application" run configuration for my Maven built project. Because i'm using Spring aspects i have to include the `spring-aspects` artifact in the run configuration's Aspect Path list. I'm adding it via the "Advanced.." button selecting "Add Classpath variable" and extending from the `M2_REPO` variable. So in the end i have a classpath variable entry in the list like this with a blue dot icon next to it:

```
M2_REPO/org/springframework/spring-aspects/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-aspects-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
```

However once i save it, Eclipse automatically replaces it in the launch file with the real path of the JAR on my machine making impossible to share the launch file with others since it's hard coding the entry to my environment.

Editing the launch file by hand doesn't help either because once i run it Eclipse replaces the expression the same way as above.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variables for classpath definition in eclipse launch configurations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557369/how-to-use-variables-for-classpath-definition-in-eclipse-launch-configurations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create the entry under the "Aspectj Load-Time weaving application" run configuration category instead of the "Aspectj/Java Application". For some strange reason the path of the Aspect is kept in it's unresolved format only with the first run configuration type. I guess it's a bug.

Obviously this makes the launch time longer because it does the waving in run time aswell. However i can't seem to find other solution.